# Powershell script parameter and dependant assembly

Tags: powershell

I have a custom PowerShell script that accept some parameters as input.

However, one of the parameters is of a type that is defined in an external assembly. That means that when I run the script from a command line with PowerShell.exe, the assembly is not loaded and the script fails.

Here is relevant parts of the script:

```
[CmdLetBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebPipeBind]$Web
)

# The SharePoint snapin will load 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
Write-Host "Let's dance"
```

And here how I fire the script (actually from a post-deployment event of a SharePoint project):

```
"%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "c:\pathto\fixeditablefields.ps1" "http://myapp"
```

Is there a way to tell PowerShell.exe to load an assembly before running the script?

**[Edit]** As I'm working with SharePoint, I'm sticked to PowerShell V2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I manage to make this works.

I launch my script using :

```
"%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command "& {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0; & 'c:\pathto\fixeditablefields.ps1' -Web 'http://myapp'}"
```

Basically, instead of running directly my script file, I run a script block which consists in running two commands : `Add-PSSnapin`, which loads my missing assembly, then execute the script with the `& c:\pathto\script.ps1` construct.

For future readers, my PostDeployment event is exactly :

```
"%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command "& {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0; & '$(SolutionDir)fixeditablefields.ps1' -Web '$(SharePointSiteUrl)'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, no. One thing you can do is prevent the script from running if the the assembly is not present by using the The #Requires statement:

```
#Requires -PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

If you don't have access to the script or cannot control it any way then i suggest to change the type of the parameter and add validations inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for you help. As I said in my edit, I'm sticked to PS V2. I actually have access to the script, but I can't hard code parameters, they must come from Visual Studio macro (look at my anwser).